# Discord.js error '.addChoice' is not a function

Tags: discord.js

i have some Problems with my Code that somehow none of my friends have ...

Some Code to see:

```
module.exports = {
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('equipment')
    .setDescription('Gives you Information about specific Equipments')
    .addStringOption(option =>
        option.setName('type')
            .setDescription('Specify the Equipment')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoice('Flashlight', 'flashlight')
        ),
...
```

The Code is Cut here because its not necesery for it above to work.

My Error Code:

```
PS C:\Users\enric\Desktop\Ghosty Phasmo Help> node .
C:\Users\enric\Desktop\Ghosty Phasmo Help\commands\phasmo\equipment.js:15
                .addChoice('Flashlight', 'flashlight')
                 ^

TypeError: option.setName(...).setDescription(...).setRequired(...).addChoice is not a function
    at C:\Users\enric\Desktop\Ghosty Phasmo Help\commands\phasmo\equipment.js:15:18
    at MixedClass._sharedAddOptionMethod (C:\Users\enric\Desktop\Ghosty Phasmo Help\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1334:50)
    at MixedClass.addStringOption (C:\Users\enric\Desktop\Ghosty Phasmo Help\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1323:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\enric\Desktop\Ghosty Phasmo Help\commands\phasmo\equipment.js:11:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
```

Somehow my Discord.js thinks that im using a Function. I copied the Code from other friends where this completely work. but somehow the same Error message appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.addChoice()` is outdated. Now, there is only `.addChoices()` (with an s)

```js
.addStringOption(option =>
    option.setName('type')
        .setDescription('Specify the Equipment')
        .setRequired(true)
        .addChoices({
            name: 'Flashlight', 
            value: 'flashlight'
        })
)
```

Comment: Why is addChoice outdated? And why can't addChoices have arrays for choices? It's confusing.

Comment: @Keilorus the discord.js developers removed it, I assume for consistency

Comment: Where did you find this information?

Comment: @Keilorus from the [discord.js Discord server](https://discord.gg/djs)